# How do I track the number of times each element is computed in Fibonacci?

Tags: python

Here's the Fibonacci sequence given:

1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21

This means that n = 8. Here's my Fibonacci code:

```
def fib(n, count= 0):
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    elif n == 1:
        return 1
    return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
```

How do I create a function to compute the number of times each element in the sequence above is computed? For example when computing fib(5), fib(0) is called 3 times, fib(1) is called 5 times, fib(2) is called 3 times etc...

I tried using a global counter but I realised that there should be a counter for each n value (correct me if I'm wrong). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by *number of times each element is computed*?

Comment: @Guy for example when computing fib(5), fib(0) is called 3 times, fib(1) is called 5 times, fib(2) is called 3 times etc...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To count how many time you call the function with a give `n` you can create a `Counter` and increment it:

```
from collections import Counter
c = Counter()

def fib(n):
    c[n] += 1
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    elif n == 1:
        return 1
    return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)

fib(8)
print(c)
# Counter({1: 21, 2: 13, 0: 13, 3: 8, 4: 5, 5: 3, 6: 2, 8: 1, 7: 1})
```

This is a nice way to see the effects of memoizing this function too. For example, here's the counts using an [`lru_cache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache):

```
from collections import Counter
from functools import lru_cache

c = Counter()

@lru_cache()
def fib(n):
    c[n] += 1
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    elif n == 1:
        return 1
    return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)

fib(8)
print(c)
#Counter({8: 1, 7: 1, 6: 1, 5: 1, 4: 1, 3: 1, 2: 1, 1: 1, 0: 1})
```

Comment: Would be far better to use decorator in order not to change `fib` code and make this a more general utility

Comment: @AndrewAllen do think introducing a decorator into this would make the concept behind this answer easier or harder to understand? I get the impression the OP is exploring recursive functions, not writing a library.

Answer (score 1):

We can intercept the function calls using a decorator.

In this decorator we can do things like printing the arguments before calling the function or in this case adding the argument calls to a Counter before calling the function. This method can be used to add timers or other functionality without amending the original function which is pythonic because *Readability counts.*

Plus the utility code written can be reused - imagine ruining every function you write if you wanted to log argument calls.

```
import functools
from collections import Counter
c = Counter()

def count_calls(f):
    @functools.wraps(f)
    def count_call(*args, **kwargs):
        c[args[0]] += 1          # add to counter
        # print('args', args)      # eg (10,)
        # print('kwargs', kwargs)  # not applicable
        return f(*args, **kwargs) # we've finished the interception, call the function
    return count_call

# original code unamended
@count_calls
def fib(n=0):
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    elif n == 1:
        return 1
    return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)

print(fib(8))
print(c)
```

Answer (score 0):

I saw the comments now. See the answer using Counter. I also upvoted it.

---

If you want n-th element: you already put `n`, so you know that.

If you want to count call including duplications:

```
calls = 0
def fib(n, count= 0):
    global calls
    calls += 1

    if n == 0:
        return 0
    elif n == 1:
        return 1
    return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
```

Comment: Thanks. I just checked the new comments.